# how to add custom view to palette in android studio?

Tags: view, android-studio, customization, palette

i made custom  view which extend textView with this constractors :

```
// Default constructor override
public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

// Default constructor when inflating from XML file
public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

how to i add it to my palette in android studio ?

i saw button that allows to to chose custom view but after i click on it nothing happen :

[image]

after i click on the class that i want the window is closed and nothing happen ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [official](http://tools.android.com/recent/customviewsinthepalette) guide to add custom views in the palette.